# My fragments are overlapping on replace

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

What's going on guys

So I have an app with two tabs and swipe navigation.

In my first tab (fragment), I added a button, that when onClick, replaces the current fragment with a new fragment using FragmentTransaction.replace(). However, what happens is when I click the button, the fragments overlap each other. I have tried nearly everything and I think it might have to do with my .xml files.

This is what is happening:

[Delivery fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAH51.jpg)

[Hitting "New Delivery" button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0aVO.jpg) Half of the new fragment is shown.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.deliverytracker;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    ViewPager   viewPager;
    ActionBar   actionBar;
    FragAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Changes fragments by user swiping
        adapter = new FragAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {  
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
        });

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab_deliv = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_deliv);
        ActionBar.Tab tab_cust  = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_cust);

        tab_deliv.setTabListener(this);
        tab_cust.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab_deliv);
        actionBar.addTab(tab_cust);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

**FragAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.deliverytracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class FragAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int TOTAL_PAGES = 2;

    public FragAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment f = null;

        // If position is 0, return Fragment A
        if(i == 0){
            f = new FragmentDeliv();
        }
        if(i == 1){
            f = new FragmentCustomers();
        }

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TOTAL_PAGES;
    }

}
```

**FragmentDeliv.java THIS IS WHERE I'm TRYING TO REPLACE THE FRAGMENT ON BUTTON CLICK**

```
package com.example.deliverytracker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FragmentDeliv extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private Button newDeliv;
    private ListView delivList;

    public FragmentDeliv() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deliv, container, false);

        setUpVars();

        newDeliv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentAddDelivery fragment = new FragmentAddDelivery();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frag_delivery, fragment, "tag");
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                //ft.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag"));   
                ft.addToBackStack("tag");
                ft.commit();
            }

        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }

    private void setUpVars() {
        newDeliv = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddDeliv);        
        delivList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listDeliv);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                         list);
        delivList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        list.add("fds");
        list.add("fds");
        list.add("fds");    
    }


}
```

**fragment_deliv.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_delivery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentDeliv" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDeliv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddDeliv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/add_delivery" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentAddDelivery.java**

```
package com.example.deliverytracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class FragmentAddDelivery extends Fragment {

    private EditText addr, city, apt, name, num, notes;

    public FragmentAddDelivery() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_delivery, container, false);

        addr  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_addr);
        city  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_city);
        apt   = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_apt);
        name  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        num   = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_num);
        notes = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_notes);

        return view;
    }
```

}

**fragment_add_delivery.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frag_add_deliv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_addr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Address (Required)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="City (Required)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_apt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Apt (Optional)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name (Optional)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number (Optional)"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Notes (Optional)"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment
>   in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If
>   you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction,
>   you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first
>   starts, as shown in the next lesson.

[Creating a fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Considering you defined a `<fragment>` tag in your xml. But from your code it seems like you're trying to replace the parent LinearLayout with a fragment? It doesn't make sense. The examples @ Google will help you.

Comment: Ah, nevermind to my previous comment I'm a bit tired. So my goal is to dynamically add the fragment with FragmentTransition. Would I need a container FrameLayout within my linear layout and pass that as the first parameter in .replace()? Let me look in to this.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

What I did was, in the fragment adapter, instead of returning the fragments I want displayed for each corresponding tab, I made a blank, root fragment for each tab that each holds its own FrameLayout container and nothing else.

In the root fragment class I have a FragmentTransaction that replaces the root frame with the fragment I originally wanted.

So for any fragment I want currently display in that tab, I just update the root_frame with a new fragment